# Creating Android AVD freezes

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo, android-virtual-device, galaxy-tab

I'm trying to setup an Android development environment. I downloaded the latest **Android SDK** and I have already installed **JDK 6** on my **64-bit ubuntu 11.04**. 
I started the AVD Manager and created an AVD with the Galaxy tab template addon and everything worked fine.

Next day, I started the AVD Manager and tried to create a new one with the Android open source project 3.2 with all default options. As soon as I click create, AVD Manager **freezes and sucks up the memory**. I tried to create one with Android open source project 2.2, and Galaxy tab addon.. same situation. I deleted my existing AVD and tried again, no luck.

I searched this issue and found some solutions for Windows but not Linux. Could anyone point me to a solution?

Answer (score 3):

How long did you wait? When I do it on 64-bit Windows, it seemingly locks up for quite a few minutes in just the manner you're describing, but it eventually finishes if left alone. Give it five to seven minutes and see if it completes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it by creating an AVD in command line.